# Animated infography JQuery or not JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Hi I am kind of lost in this subject, is not my area of expertise. I am trying to make a animation through JS. Just an arrow going up to the sky and showing trending something like an animated infographic.

But I don't know how exactly start if I do it with canvas or do it animating images in JQuery? try to loop a Background vertical to mimic the effect of the arrow going up.

If anyone can suggest a good approach for this. It will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a parallax scroll would be a really cool way to go in my opinion.  [Check it out how to do such an effect here.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/)  I (and the tutorial) would suggest using [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/).

It may not be the "animation" that you're looking for (I'd suggest using canvas to display javascript code personally), but it creates a pretty cool effect where the background will scroll at a different speed than the elements on top of it.

Comment: you my friend lead me to my answer this is pretty like what I want to do!!! http://www.intacto10years.com/index_start.php Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: That's some pretty impressive stuff!  Hopefully you're able to achieve much the same effect.